# How do I connect to the same MongoDB database with node.js and the console?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell

Using mongoose I connect to a Mongodb database on my local machine. I'm using `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myTestDB');`. Then in a console I enter the Mongodb shell with `mongo`. However, I can't find the myTestDB database inside the mongodb shell with the `show dbs` command. What gives? How do peruse the same database nodejs is connecting to in the shell?

Comment: Your started your mongo database with `mongod` then you used mongo shell `mongo`. When you enter `show dbs`do you see at least `local` database?

Comment: I see **jwt 0.078GB** and **test 0.078GB**. Then I type **use jwt** and **db.jwt.find()** but none of the documents created by node.js and mongoose show. I can access the documents through node.js. Also, I can create records inside the shell which I can retrieve inside the shell. It's like I'm connected to two different databases but I don't know where each is or how to connect to them in different ways.

Comment: Have you actually done anything with the database you are connecting to with mongoose? Until you actually create a document in a collection neither collection or data will exist.

Comment: I had deleted the **admin** and the **local** databases as I carelessly cleaned things up. Is that what is causing the problem? I restarted my computer and those databases exist again. Still doesn't work though.

Comment: As already said, create a document to this database (from Mongo shell in a first time). Then it will create it and you will see it even through mongoose.

Comment: I have no problem connecting to the database through nodejs and insert and find documents. I have no problem inserting a document through the shell of the same structure and then finding that document in the shell. I just can't access documents created in nodejs from the shell and documents created in the shell from nodejs. I'm so confused because i created a new database and it's like they are using the same file on the disk.

Comment: How are you running the MongoDB server? Through `mongod` command I presume? If so what's its output? Should be something like `MongoDB starting : pid=6776 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data` Also, could you then check in that `dbpath` whether your database file exists. If not, could you search your PC for "myTestDB" in files to see if it exists somewhere else?

Comment: **mtTestDB** exists in the configured --dbpath at /var/lib/mongodb. When I connected to a new database through node.js name **newDB** it was created. When I made a new database **shellDB** it was created once again in that folder. I can connect to all databases through either the shell or node.js. I just can't access data inserted by each while in the other. I'm perplexed.

Comment: You said above that you tried `db.jwt.find()` which isn't how it works. Do `show collections` which will display collection names in the `jwt` database and and then do `db.collection.find()`

Comment: Yes, that is it. I should have been working with collections. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your database should atleast have one document in the collection, only then it will be listed in the mongo shell.

Answer (score -1):

From the comments and your description it seems you aren't starting MongoDB through `mongod`. You first need to establish a connection to your database file (should have *journal* , *"databaseName" .0 and .ns*, *mongod.lock* and *storage.bson* files inside). Setting up your `dbpath` alone won't connect to it unless you explicitly do so in console.

If you don't want to store your database file locally you can use [mongolab](http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/).

Follow [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) manual (Run MongoDB section) and it should work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).